# Block user IP's with .htaccess or PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess

From a performance only view, which would be the best way to block 30 IP addresses?

A) .htaccess file

or

B) PHP code in the file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are administrator of your server, I would use none of those, and would ban the IPs at the firewall level -- this way, nor Apache nor Apache+PHP will have to work.

If you're not admin ; well, `.htaccess` means only Apache, and no PHP to load/compile/execute ; I'm guessing Apache alone *(i.e. `.htaccess`)* should require less resources than Apache+PHP.

Another way of seing things is maintenance : if you need to add/delete IPs addresses from that list, what would the easiest way be ? 

*(In that case, I would generally bet for some PHP code...)*

Comment: Thanks, I am curious, would it be possible to write a PHP script that could add/remove IP's being blocked at the server firewall level?

Comment: I suppose it would be possible -- provided the user than runs the PHP scripts has the privileges required to do that kind of action ;; and not sure the user that runs Apache has that kind of power... *(I have to admit I've never tried, actually)*

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Pascal's answer. But the PHP code is:

```
$banned = array('129.168.1.1');
if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $banned))
{
    die();
}
```

And the .htaccess is:

```
order allow,deny
deny from 192.168.1.1
allow from all
```

Just for the record.

Comment: Yeah I use something like that now but I am thinking of doing it at a server level before PHP hopefully –

Comment: I would check the X_HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR header too if using PHP.

Comment: Yeah, there would probably be a little more processing, but the basic elements are there.

Answer (score 3):

`Hardware`

or

`Hardware + OS`

or

`Hardware + OS + Apache`

or

`Hardware + OS + Apache + PHP`

Understanding the stacks should help indicate which will be the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

Why not block them at the hardware level (router, load balancer, firewall, etc)? - If its only a block of 30 and you don't need to update them often.

Comment: I will deffinately look into this, looking at all option right now

Answer (score 0):

[@MikeB 's answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2090186/318765) it perfectly. Nevertheless I use PHP and .htaccess in combination as they are easier to maintain and I'm able to use [honeypots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot_(computing)) to automatically add new IPs. Example:

login.php

```
if ($login_tries > 3) {
    touch('deny/' . $_SERVER['REMOT_ADDR']);
}
```

.htaccess

```
# check if ip has been banned
RewriteCond /usr/www/{YOUR_PATH}/deny/%{REMOTE_ADDR} -f
RewriteRule . - [F]
```

But the main reason why I use this is to allow accidentally blocked visitors to [unblock themself through a captcha](https://www.maxrev.de/php-firewall-blockt-nun-ips-von-spam-bots-t234957.htm).